# What is "Accept-EncodXng" in Apache config?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This appears in .htaccess in HTML5 boilerplate.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
```

Is "Accept-EncodXng" documented somewhere?

Comment: It just seems to be a common "mangling" of the `Accept-Encoding` header? [This book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E7p-07kNfXYC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=Accept-EncodXng&source=bl&ots=UNeoTJlfNs&sig=sMTz92FGJKQaXMGREdPJKM8IUh0&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Accept-EncodXng&f=false) makes reference to this particular header, and the other one in your code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting! Apparently, this is because some proxies and security software obfuscate the `Accept-Encoding` header, which has the negative effect of requesting the server respond without GZIP compression.

Apparently this information comes from the book **Even Faster Web Sites: Performance Best Practices for Web Developers**, with the relevant information being available in the [Going beyond gzipping](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/29/Beyond%20Gzipping%20Presentation.pdf) slides. The following is the table of software which strips or obfuscates the header from the PDF slides.

> ```
> ------------------------------+-------------------------------
> Software                      | Accept-Encoding modification
> ------------------------------+-------------------------------
> Ad Muncher                    | Stripped
> CA Internet Security Suite    | Accept-EncodXng: gzip, deflate
> CEQURUX                       | Stripped
> Citrix Application Firewall   | Stripped
> ISA 2006                      | Stripped
> McAfee Internet Security 6.0  | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: +++++++++++++
> Norton Internet Security 2005 | ---------------: -------------
> Novell iChain 2.3             | Stripped
> Novell Client Firewall        | Stripped
> WebWasher                     | Stripped
> ZoneAlarm Pro 5.5             | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
> ```

Those slides also reference `X-cept-Encoding`, though I don't see it listed in the table.

Comment: ...and these software supposedly do this because they "need to observe (or, if you prefer, spy on) the responses sent by the web server. Observing a response is cheaper in terms of CPU usage if the response does not have to be decompressed first."

Comment: @w3d Thanks for the quote. I wonder if that's the actually reason. I can't think of any other reasons, but if it is, that's just stupid.

Comment: Yes, you have to wonder. The book basically says it's stupid as well.